# I made a mistake in the equation of the line, but why?

Tags: geometry

I need write the equation of the line pass through $A(4; 0; 1)$ parallel to $BD$.

$B(0; 0; 1)$, $D(1; 0; -1)$

I found $\overline{BD}= \{1; 0; -2\}$, and, next:

$\frac{ x - 4 }{ 1 } = \frac{ y - 0 }{ 0 } = \frac{ z - 1 }{ -2 }$

But $\frac{ y - 0 }{ 0 }$ - is a mistake?

Comment: Your steps are fine for most cases.  As you have observed, y is constant on this line.  So rather than fit it into the simultaneous equations, it will have to exist as a separate remark.  $x-4 = -\frac {z-1}{2}, y=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know where does the equation $\frac{x-4}1=\frac{y-0}0=\frac{z-1}{-2}$ comes from ?

In fact write the line as $M=A+t\vec{BD}$ where $M=(x;y;z)$

You get $\begin{cases}x=4+1t\\y=0+0t\\z=1-2t\end{cases}$

As DougM said, you see that $y=0$ is constant on that line.

The equation actually comes from isolating $t$.

Indeed $t=\dfrac{x-4}1=\dfrac{z-1}{-2}$

Yet of course, this won't work for $y$ since $y$ doesn't actually depends on $t$.

Comment: And, $\frac{ x - 4 }{ 1 } = \frac{ y - 0 }{ 0 } = \frac{ z - 1 }{ -2 }$ - it is right?

Comment: $y=0+0t$ makes sense but not $t=\frac{y-0}0$. There is no choice here but to represent the line by the intersection of two plans, i.e plan $8-x=z-1$ and plan $y=0$.